# PostGIS update field in polygon attribute table based on state it intersects with

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I know I could do this quickly in Qgis, but I'm trying to learn post and SQL.
I have a table containing numerous polygons across the United States with an empty field I created called "state". I want to update this field with an abbreviation based on the state it intersects with, but my query is not correct.

The datasets are: census_blocks (polygon) and us_states (polygon)
My current SQL is as follows:

```
UPDATE census_blocks
SET "state"= us_states.abbrev
FROM us_states, census_blocks
WHERE st_intersects(census_blocks.geom, us_states)
```

The error message returns something like: SQL error: ....returned 0 does not exist ...

I copied some of the syntax from some other posts, but can't get their answers to work with my specific datasets. I'm very much a beginner with SQL and would appreciate any help.

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html requires two geometry. census_blocks.geom maybe a geometry data type. but us_states is a table. which is not a geometry data type. show us your create table script.

Comment: Please be aware, that this update might lead to wrong results: if a _census_block_ shares a line segment with an _us_state_, they intersect. _Census_blocks_ at a boundary therefore intersect with the _us_state_ wich they relate to, but also to the neighbour state. You could / should use
`UPDATE ... WHERE st_intersects(ST_Centroid(census_blocks.geom), us_states.geom)`

Comment: Update: This is a working example: `UPDATE census_blocks
SET "state"= (SELECT us_states.abbrev
FROM us_states, census_blocks
WHERE st_intersects(st_Centroid(census_blocks.geom), us_states.geom))`